# How to send notifications even if app is closed or phone is restarted in xamarin forms?

Tags: forms, xamarin, notifications

I am new in mobile programming. I need an application. This application periodically will check web api to get whether the client has a new massage or not. If there is a new massage, this massage will be informed to the client by notification. I achieved this but it works if application is open. Then I used foreground services, but it failed when phone is restarted. I need a notification system like whatsapp or telegram. We can get notifications about new massage even if the apps are closed or when we restart phone.

Please help me.

Comment: you need to use push notifications

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using Firebase push notifications - [sample](https://github.com/Denys2211/FirebaseTestNotification)